# Type name T undefined when creating a mutable binary tree

Tags: pointers, data-structures, tree, rust, binary-tree

I am new to Rust, and for an exercise, I am building a simple generic binary tree. This is how I'd create one in C++

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node<T>* parent;
    Node<T>* left;
    Node<T>* right;
};

template<typename T>
struct Bintree
{
    Node<T>* root;  
};
```

But the same(ish) code in Rust doesn't seem to work:

```
use std::ptr;

struct Node<T> {
    data: T,
    left: &Node<T>,
    right: &Node<T>,
    parent: &Node<T>,
}

struct Tree<T> {
    root: &Node<T>,
}

impl Tree<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Tree<T> {
        Tree { root: ptr::null() }
    }

    pub fn insert(&self, value: T) {
        if root.is_null() {
            self.root = Node {
                data: value,
                left: ptr::null(),
                right: ptr::null(),
                parent: ptr::null(),
            };
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

And here's the error:

```
error[E0412]: type name `T` is undefined or not in scope
  --> src/main.rs:14:15
   |
14 |     impl Tree<T> {
   |               ^ undefined or not in scope
   |
   = help: no candidates by the name of `T` found in your project; maybe you misspelled the name or forgot to import an external crate?

error[E0412]: type name `T` is undefined or not in scope
  --> src/main.rs:15:30
   |
15 |         pub fn new() -> Tree<T> {
   |                              ^ undefined or not in scope
   |
   = help: no candidates by the name of `T` found in your project; maybe you misspelled the name or forgot to import an external crate?

error[E0412]: type name `T` is undefined or not in scope
  --> src/main.rs:19:37
   |
19 |         pub fn insert(&self, value: T) {
   |                                     ^ undefined or not in scope
   |
   = help: no candidates by the name of `T` found in your project; maybe you misspelled the name or forgot to import an external crate?

error[E0425]: unresolved name `root`. Did you mean `self.root`?
  --> src/main.rs:20:16
   |
20 |             if root.is_null() {
   |                ^^^^

error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:5:15
  |
5 |         left: &Node<T>,
  |               ^ expected lifetime parameter

error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:6:16
  |
6 |         right: &Node<T>,
  |                ^ expected lifetime parameter

error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:7:17
  |
7 |         parent: &Node<T>,
  |                 ^ expected lifetime parameter

error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/main.rs:11:15
   |
11 |         root: &Node<T>,
   |               ^ expected lifetime parameter
```

I don't really understand what's wrong with that. I don't really get how Rust's pointers work.

Answer (score 7):

In this case, you have a basic syntax error, it should be

```
impl<T> Tree<T>
```

From there, you'll see that you need `if self.root.is_null()`.

Then, the data structure needs lifetime specifiers, since you are using references. Using the most straightforward of that syntax eventually leads to

```
error[E0309]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
```

So you use `T: 'a` there... and you end up with:

```
use std::ptr;

struct Node<'a, T: 'a> {
    data: T,
    left: &'a Node<'a, T>,
    right: &'a Node<'a, T>,
    parent: &'a Node<'a, T>,
}

struct Tree<'a, T: 'a> {
    root: &'a Node<'a, T>,
}

impl<'a, T> Tree<'a, T> {
    pub fn new() -> Tree<'a, T> {
        Tree { root: ptr::null() }
    }

    pub fn insert(&self, value: T) {
        if self.root.is_null() {
            self.root = Node {
                data: value,
                left: ptr::null(),
                right: ptr::null(),
                parent: ptr::null(),
            };
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

This gives another error

```
21 |             root: ptr::null(),
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected reference, found *-ptr
```

This is because `ptr::null()` returns raw pointers, but you've declared that your data structure uses references.

Okay, that's as far as I'm going to go. Let's go back to your question...

> I am new to Rust, and for an exercise, I am building a simple generic binary tree.

I would suggest that you should consider something *other* than writing a data structure. They're not simple in Rust. If you still want to do this approach, may I recommend [Too Many Lists](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/).

Comment: I found an answer (see the post below), but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to do it. I used `std::optional` instead of `std::ptr` for the node struct, and it works like a C pointer.

```
struct Node<T> {
    id: u32,
    data: T,
    left: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    parent: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

struct Tree<T> {
    root: Option<Node<T>>,
}

impl<T> Node<T> {
    pub fn new(value: Option<T>,
               left: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
               right: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
               parent: Option<Box<Node<T>>>)
               -> Node<T> {
        Node {
            data: value.unwrap(),
            left: left,
            right: right,
            parent: parent,
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Tree<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Tree<T> {
        Tree { root: None }
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T) {
        match self.root {
            Some(ref n) => {
                println!("Root is not empty");
            }
            None => {
                println!("Root is empty");
                self.root = Some(Node::new(Some(value), None, None, None));
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    let mut tree: Tree<i32> = Tree::new();
    tree.insert(42);
}
```

Comment: `Box` is a pointer that owns the thing it points to. A node owning the children sound good, but a node can't own its parent. The parent pointer is what makes your data structure graphlike, it has a referential cycle, and neither Box nor Rust's regular references can deal with this. It is relatively straightforward to use a raw pointer for the parent pointer.